# Representations of simply connected Lie groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a simply connected Lie group. Is it true that any finite dimensional representation of its Lie algebra is the differential of a representation of $G$?

A reference would be helpful.

Sorry if the question is too basic.

Comment: Yes, but the question would be indeed more appropriate for MSE. Look at [Simply connected Lie groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group#Lie_group_versus_Lie_algebra_isomorphisms) in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A finite-dimensional representation of a Lie algebra is in particular a homomorphism of finite-dimensional Lie algebras. Hence your question is answered in the affirmative e.g. by Th. 3.27 in F. Warner's book "Foundations of differential geometry and Lie groups".